# How can I read a specific value from a .data table in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a specific value from a data table and assign it to a variable.  These .data tables have two separators: a space and a tab.  Each table contains values from an individual `cell` that I need to assign to a variable (I made a for loop already but I need the variables to be assigned). I am unsure which module to use to complete this task.

Comment: can you post your try ?

Comment: What is a data table? Can you be a bit more specific about which technology you are using?